# Doubling Map and Measure

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

First off!  This is a homework question, so I DO NOT want an answer to the question I'm writing, I really just want an explanation of the final bit (which I'll make clear).

So if we have $T:[0,1)\to [0,1),Tx=2x \text{mod} 1$ which preserves Lebesgue measure $m$, then we have $\phi:[0,1)\to[0,1)$ defined as $\phi(x)=x^3$. Find
$$\lim_{n\to ∞} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \phi(T^j x)$$
for $m$ almost every point $x\in [0,1)$.

So essentially, my question is "what does it mean 'Find **** for m almost every point x'?"  My question really is that I don't know what I'm computing? Does it mean compute $m(***)?$ If that's the case, I think I have a few ideas....

Comment: Fun question. I would start by using the fact that if $x\equiv x+2^{-k}\pmod1$ for some natural number $k$, then the sequences $(T^jx)$ and $(T^jx')$ share the infinite tail, but I really don't see where that leads? Also if $x$ is rational, then the sequence is eventually periodic. But I think that I'm approaching this limit from the atypical as opposed to a.e. side :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In measure theory, we say a property holds "almost everywhere" if the set of elements for which it doesn't hold has measure zero. Clearly, this definition depends on the measure, so we might say "$m$-almost everywhere" if it's not clear from context.

In this case, what we're saying is, find an expression $f(x)$ such that the equation
\[f(x) = \lim_{n\to ∞} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \phi(T^j x) \tag{1}\]
holds $m$-almost everywhere in $[0,1)$, i.e. $m(\{x \in [0,1) : \text{(1) doesn't hold}\}) = 0$.

Of course such an $f$ will be non-unique. But that's probably okay – whoever is asking the question doesn't mind which you choose.